# Message is not sending in some phones by smsManager

Tags: android, message, smsmanager

I am tring to send message by smsManager. But in some of the samsung phone it is not able to send and no error is displayed.

Here is my code

```
 try {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    Toast.makeText(context, "" + phoneNumber + ": " + messageText,  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumbers, null, messageText, sentPI, deliveredPI);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Sms not Send  " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Even I used `com.klinker.android.send_message` but it is not executing even

```
[2013-10-29 13:57:50 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/gson/JsonSerializer;
[2013-10-29 13:57:50 - kluebook] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/gson/JsonSerializer;
```

`

Comment: Try updating your ADT plugin. or create a new workspace and try

Comment: Not resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

1.) Restart Eclipse.

2.) Delete `bin` and `gen` folder.

3.) `Clean` the project and `build` it again.

Comment: First of all i need to know is it possible by SmsManager to send sms by all mobile companies..? Or we should use a library to support all

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android 6.0 and above, add codes for runtime permissions in your project.